# sending object as link parameter inside razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

inside my mvc razor view I'm getting list of objects and inside foreach loop I'm creating links like

```
@{ 
    var dday = @ViewBag.Day;     
}
@foreach (var a in Model)
{
   <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(a.Name, "ProcessAction", "Home", new { ss= @a.Id, dd= dday, cc= @a.Comp}, null)            
   </li>
}
```

on controller side I'm getting first two variables populated and third parameter as null even `@a.Comp` is populated in the moment of sending inside link.

On link mouse over I'm getting third argument as Domain.Comp

Comment: What type is `a.Comp`? You can't pass an object this way.

Comment: is of type  Domain.Comp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot transfer arbitrary objects as URL parameters. Restrict yourself to strings and numbers, dates can already be tricky.

In your case it looks like you should use: `cc= @a.Comp.Id`.

You should be able to retrieve the object serverside from its Id.